# Verification of a proof involving metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I've got this problem:

If $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are homeomorphic metric spaces, then they have the same convergence sequences.
    However, there exists homeomorphic metric spaces $(X,d)$, $(X,d')$ such that only one of them is complete.

So for the first part I did the following, since we have that $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are homeomorphic then they have the same topology (this is, they have the same open sets), this means that if $(x_{n})$ is convergent in $(X,d)$, say to $x$ ($x$ is not necessarily in $X$, "with convergent in" we only refer that the sequence $(x_n) \in X$ converges), there exists $N \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ such that for all open set $U$ that contains $x$ implies that $x_n \in U$ for $n \geq N$ but $U$ is open in $(X,d')$ too, and $x_n \in X$ for all $n$ therefore $x_n$ in convergent in $(X,d')$

So, Can you tell me if I am right?, If not Can you help me to prove this in a good way?

And for part 2 I haven't found a example with respect to the same space $X$ Can someone give an example of this please :)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're assuming not just that $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are homeomorphic but that in fact the identity map on $X$ is a homeomorphism. (Which seems like probably what was intended, but it's not the hypothesis you stated here...)

Comment: So how can I fix it?, and can you explain in more detail my mistake please, because I dont get it :) Thanks.

Comment: So , how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Simply clarify that that's what you're assuming...

Comment: mm I don't get it

Comment: I would follow @DavidC.Ullrich's suggestion, assuming that $d$ and $d'$ are _equivalent_, that is the identity map $i: (X,d) \rightarrow (X,d')$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the object of your post is a couple of metrics $d$ and $d'$ defined on the same set $X$ in such a way that the identity map $i: (X,d) \rightarrow (X,d')$ is continuous together with its inverse.

**First question**

Remember the sequential criterium for continuity, that is

> A function $f: (X,d) \rightarrow (X',d')$ is continuous at $x \in X\,$ iff $\,f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ .

**Second question**

> The point is that $d$ and $d'$ can have the same convergent sequences but not the same Cauchy sequences.

Let $X=\mathbb R\,$ and $\,d(s,t)=|s-t|$.

Define $d'$ in the following way.

Consider the circle of center $(0,1)$ and radius $1$. Denote by $P_s$ the second point of intersection of the circle with the line passing through $(s,0)$ and $(0,2)$. Let $d'(s,t)$ equal to the euclidean distance between $P_s$ and $P_t$.

One can show that $d'$ is a metric on $\mathbb R$ and, moreover, $d$ and $d'$ have the same convergent sequences.
Now $\{n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb R,d')$ but not in $(\mathbb R,d)$, so $(\mathbb R,d')$ is not complete.

The above example is from J. Conway *A Course in Point Set Topology* (2014), p. 20 .